# How to calculate this limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left[\left(n+\frac 32\right)^{\frac 13} - \left(n+ \frac 12\right)^{\frac 13}\right]$?

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I tried rationalizing this [multiplying and dividing by $(n+\frac 32)^{\frac 13} + (n+ \frac 12)^{\frac 13}$ but then the numerator contains terms of power $\frac 23$. So I couldn't move forward.

What are methods to evaluate this?

**PS :** While typing this question I got this,

$(n+\frac 32)^{\frac 13} - (n+ \frac 12)^{\frac 13}=\dfrac {(1+ \frac 3{2n})^{\frac 13} - (1+ \frac 1{2n})^{\frac 13}}{n^{-\frac 13}}.$

Now I apply L'hospital rule and get,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} [(n+\frac 32)^{\frac 13} - (n+ \frac 12)^{\frac 13}]=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac 1{2n^{\frac 23}}[(1 + \frac 3{2n})^{-\frac 23}-(1+\frac 1{2n})^{-\frac 23}]=0$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**:
You should multiply and divide by $$(n+\frac 32)^{\frac 23}+(n+\frac 32)^{\frac 13}(n+ \frac 12)^{\frac 13}+(n+ \frac 12)^{\frac 23}$$ to rationalize this as
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
The rest should be simple...

Comment: Ah! Silly me...

Answer (score 1):

Use *Taylor's formula* at order $1$:
\begin{align}(n+\frac 32)^{\frac 13} - (n+ \frac 12)^{\frac 13}&=n^{\frac 13}\biggl(\Bigl(1+\frac3{2n}\Bigr)^{\frac 13}-\Bigl(1+\frac1{2n}\Bigr)^{\frac 13}\biggr)\\
&=n^{\frac 13}\biggl(1+\frac1{2n}+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)-1-\frac1{6n}-o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\biggr)\\
&=n^{\frac 13}\cdot\biggl(\frac1{3n}+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\biggr)=\frac1{3n^{\frac23}}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n^{\frac23}}\Bigr)\to0.
\end{align}